# Can't upgrade to Magento Commerce 2.2.3

Tags: magento-enterprise, composer

Trying to upgrade `Magento Commerce` (EE) to `2.2.3` from `2.2.2` using `composer`, however, the package doesn't seem to be available in `repo.magento.com` - anyone else had this problem?

Tried a lot of debugging, composer cache clearing, etc, but got me nowhere.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

---

### Update

Turns out it was another composer-installed module that was preventing me from doing the upgrade, unfortunately still don't know to this day why composer didn't tell me about it, the way it usually does in these situations.

Oh well, panic over!

Comment: If you are using EE then they will provide you procedure to upgrade.

Comment: That is the problem, following the documentation and is failing. However, tying different other things and I think I'm on to something, but as I said, still doing some tests before updating this post.

Comment: Small update: there seems to be a problem in that repo somehow, tried to copy the `composer.json` file alone in a new dir and triggered the usual `composer require [...]` and `composer update` and worked like a charm. There must be a constrain somewhere/somehow, just didn't find it yet.